How to solve the problem that hibernate methods do not work
I created a hibernate project using spring although it has any error/warning, anyone of hibernate methods works. Here is my code:
Student.java
public class Student {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String dept;
    //getters and setters

}
StudentDao.java
public class StudentDao{

    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void saveStudent(Student s){
        template.save(s);
    }

}

Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        StudentDao studentDao = (StudentDao) ctx.getBean("st");

        Student s=new Student();
        s.setId(5);
        s.setName("Messi");
        s.setDept("Physics");
        studentDao.saveStudent(s);
        System.out.println(" Successfully persisted the student. Please check your database for results.");

    }
}

Configuration files are like that:
applicationContext.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="localSessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>student.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactory"></property>
        <property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="st" class="example.StudentDao">
        <property name="template" ref="hibernateTemplate"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>

student.hbm.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="example.Student" table="student">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name"></property>
        <property name="dept"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

I think the problem is about configuration files but I can not find it.

The problem was Java4+ versions dont support hibernateTemplate. I changed it to hibernate3 and the issue is resolved
